# Java while loop boolean evaluation

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean-expression

I am not sure if i understand this loop

```
boolean b = false;
while(!b) {
System.out.println(b);
b = !b;
}
```

> it returns a false, loop is executed once

but does `while(!b)` set `b= true` ? like `!b = !false` and `b` is printed out?

Comment: No, `b = !b` does that. It inverts `b`.

Answer (score 11):

The `while (!b)` condition does not set `b` to `true`.

The `b = !b` statement does.

That's why your loop executes only once.

---

Translation in pseudo-code:

- while `not b` (that is, while `b` is `false`)
- print `b` (so print `false`)
- assign `b` to `not b`, that is, the opposite of `b` (so assign `b` to `true`)
- next iteration of the loop, `b` is `true`, so `not b` condition fails and loop terminates

Answer (score 2):

Translated:

```
 boolean b = false;
 while(b == false) {
 System.out.println(b);
 b = !b;  // b becomes true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(!b) {    // As b = false but due to ! condition becomes true not b
System.out.println(b);  //false will be printed
b = !b;  // b = !false i.e. now b is true 
}
```

As now **b** is true so in next iteration the condition will be false and you will exist from loop

Answer (score 0):

`!` is the negation unary operator in Java a do not modify the operand.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean b = false;
while(!b) { // The !b basically means "continue loop while b is not equal to true"
System.out.println(b);
b = !b; // this line is setting variable b to true. This is why your loop only processes once.
}
```